# Why can't Xamarin import Spongy Castle?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get tons of error regarding SpongyCastle's auto-generated .cs files after importing them, even though Xamarin generated them.

The Java library that I created needs the dependency, and I imported it into the Jars folder together with my Java library.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a Java library that is referenced by your Java library and you do not need to access it via C# user code, then you do not need to create a C# bindings for it.

Flag that `.jar`/`.aar` with a build type of:

`EmbeddedReferenceJar` : Use this to compile against **and** include it in your binding library.

or

`ReferenceJar` : Use this to compile against but **not** include it in your binding library. You will need to supply it in your final APK in another way.

Re: [Build Actions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/#Build_Actions)

Comment: Hi, I marked all dependency jars of my library's jar as `EmbeddedReferenceJar`. However, I get the Java Exception when I'm trying to use it: `Failed resolution of: Lcom/nimbusds/jose/Algorithm;`

Comment: @user3635998 Do you have `nimbus-jose-jwt-{X}.{X}.jar` in your project?

Comment: Yes I do, and I marked it as an `EmbeddedReferenceJar`. So... What must I do to resolve this?

Comment: @user3635998 Would have not idea without seeing the project, but you should dump the dex file from the apk and see if that method(s) is there. (Also *assuming* you do not have proguard enabled and are not stripping it out)

Comment: This is really puzzling. I reversed the APK and `com.nimbusds.jose.Algorithm` exists.

Comment: @user3635998 Does your code work in a pure Android Java app? A google search had several hits on the failed resolution of Algorithm related to a cert not verifying, etc... I'm aware of, but never used that library myself, maybe answer another question including your code and the exception/stack...

Comment: Yep. Works perfectly in pure Android. Only encounter issues when I use Xamarin.